# Hide a character in textField using TextFormat in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a textfield with a text and I need to hide the last character

I tried

```
    _textField.text = "My string";
    var newtextFormat:TextFormat =  new TextFormat();
    newtextFormat.size = 0;
    _textField.setTextFormat(newtextFormat, _textField.length-1, _textField.length-1);
```

the issue is that last charter is still visible like a single pixel.
Is there any way to set the font color transparent 
for example

```
newtextFormat.color = <any tranparent color>;
```

Comment: Why don't you just strip off the the last letter?   `_textField.text = _textField.text.substr(0, _textField.text.length - 1);`  If behind your text is a solid color, leave the size as is and just change the text format to same color as the background.

Comment: background color is not uniform.. I will try your suggestion but I doubt it would destroy the text format of the rest

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing size or alpha, I would recomend you replacing text string inside of your textField with blank field(" "), like this:

```
_textField.text = "My string";
var newString:String=_textField.text.replace (_textField.text.charAt (_textField.text.length-1) , " ");

_textField.text =newString;
//now textField text is My strin
```

If you want that to be some other character, not the last one, you can easily change it to e.g.

```
_textField.text = "My string";
var newString:String=_textField.text.replace (_textField.text.charAt (3) , " ");

_textField.text =newString;
//now textField text is My  tring
```

Comment: @user3264864 - You do not want to use the replace method...  it will replace all instances of that character.  You clearly state you want just the last character hidden.   If you're going to change the actual text of the text field, use the code in my comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a textfield's "restrict" feature to determine what sorts of characters can be typed.  You can listen to the "change" event and edit what they typed.